# Iterating over an infinite container with a stop point in python

Tags: python

Suppose I want to generate a list of the set of positive integers whose square is less than 100 in python.

My initial thinking was to do something like this

```
from itertools import count
numbers = [x for x in count() if x**2<100]
```

However this code won't complete, as python goes through infinitely many numbers.

There are two solutions to this as far as I can tell:

1. Put in a bound on the range of integers to go over, so use range(1000) instead of count() above.
2. Use a while loop, incrementing x and stopping the loop when x squared is greater than or equal to 100.

Neither of these solutions are elegant or (as far as I can tell) *pythonic*. Is there a good way to handle cases like this ,when iterating over an infinite container but you know that the loop stops at some point.

Thanks!

Comment: You could just use a for-loop as well, and break out of it when necessary, which is perfectly Pythonic. Don't associate Pythonic with "uses list comprehensions for everything"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `takewhile`:

```
nums = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x**2 < 100, count())
```

Literally, take while the square is less than 100

Answer (score 6):

This would be a use case for [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import count, takewhile

numbers = list(takewhile(lambda x: x**2 < 100, count()))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

For a slice of known bounds from a (infinite) generator (not all of those have such simple finite equivalents as `range`), use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
numbers = list(islice(count(), 4, 10, 2))
# [4, 6, 8]
```

That being said, and with a loop-based approach being perfectly legit as well, there is a hacky way of achieving it in one line without any library tools, by causing an "artificial" [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration):

```
numbers = list(x if x**2<100 else next(iter([])) for x in count())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

don't do this in serious code though - not just because [it will stop working in Python3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/#examples-of-breakage) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use range, I would write it like this.

```
import math
[x for x in range(int(math.sqrt(100))+1) if (x**2) < 100]
```

You can change 100 to what you like or set it as a variable, but you know the list of numbers will end at the square root of your target number.